# Shared subroutines & value parsing

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using a project with 2 windows forms, one *home form* with an ultragrid, displaying some data, the other to _dd data to it. 
I want to refresh the ultragrid when the *add data form* is closed, but currently cannot do so.

I need to make the add data form `form_closing` subroutine a `Public Shared Sub` to allow me to get the `ShowDialog.OK` value using the subroutine on the home form that loads the data, so it knows whether or not to refresh it. However, because it's a shared sub, I cannot use `Me.Dispose`. How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub fHome_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' This is where the UltraGrid gets it's data from

    If fAdd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        uwgDisplay.DataSource = Nothing
        displayData()

' addData form is open, then get the data from the database (dont refresh it)

    Else
displayData()

' if add data form is closed, then refresh the data
    End If

    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)

End Sub
```

This is the form closing sub on the add form

```
  Public Shared Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If Globals.savedValue = False Then

        Dim closeBox As MsgBoxResult
        closeBox = MsgBox("Exit without saving?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
        If closeBox = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Dispose()

        ElseIf closeBox = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Me.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

On both `Me.Dispose()` lines I am told

> Me is only valid within an instance method

Comment: So, to summarise, what you need is the `fHome_Load` subroutine to use the value from 'Form_FormClosing``ShowDialog` function (which you've not added yet, by the way), but cannot do so as making it a `Public Shared Sub` means you aren't sure how to close it?

Comment: @David yes, that's correct

Comment: @MattWilko When I tried using `If fAdd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK` without it being a shared sub, it said


`Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference`

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> "I'm needing to make the add data form form_closing subroutine a
>   Public Shared Sub to allow me to get the ShowDialog.OK"

Is incorrect. you don't need to make the FormClosing method  shared to get the DialogResult

```
Private _myform As frmFoo

Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    If _myform Is Nothing Then _myForm = New frmFoo
    If _myform.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        'do something 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, how do I do it? What code would I use in each subroutine? (I'm new to ShowDialog and have never used it before)

Comment: Hi Matt, this worked in part, however since this is creating 'New fAdd` the add data form now opens with the home form, how do I adapt the code to prevent this?

Comment: It shouldn't do unless you are showing the fAdd form in the constructor (Public Sub New) or something. Anyway you can just instantiate it in the button. See my update